# Cannot deserialize instance of boolean from VALUE_STRING value Yes or request may be missing a required field

Tags: java, json, salesforce

I am having issue while updating object in Sales force using Force API.

Object that I am going to update:

```
{id=null, accountId=null, contactId=null, status=STATUS_COMPLETED, category=null, type=null, createdDate=null, origin=null, submittedDate=null, paperDeclarationRequested=false, targetPolicy=null, policyNumber=null, caseStatus=STATUS_COMPLETED, recordType=null, sdpStatus=null, dipDate=null, unabletoLinkDate=null, currentDate=null, recordTypeId=null, investmentFundName=SBI Fund, dateOfLatestConsent=Fri Jun 17 05:30:00 IST 2016, dataConsentIndicator=true, subject=null, paperDocumentsRequested=true, title=Personal Details, firstName=Asif, surname=Billa, dateOfBirth=Thu Oct 25 05:30:00 IST 1990, nationalInsuranceNumber=123456, countryOfNationality=India, ukResidentIndicator=Yes, crownServiceOrArmedForcesEmployeeIndicator=crownService, countryOfTaxResidency=United Kingdom, taxReferenceNumber=wert234, townOfBirth=London, nonUkResidentIndicator=Yes, addressLine1=yemlur, addressLine2=abc, addressLine3=karnataka, town=London, country=United Kingdom, postCode=B46 5EW, previousAddressLine1=null, previousAddressLine2=null, previousAddressLine3=null, previousTown=null, previousCountry=null, previousPostCode=null, contactTelephoneNumber=123345, accountName=Prashant, accountNumber=123142342, buildingSocietyRollNumber=12345, sortCode=null, singlePaymentAmount=5000, regularMonthlyPaymentAmount=5000, regularMonthlyPaymentStartDate=Thu May 26 04:04:51 IST 2016, withdrawalAmount=5000, frequency=Monthly, withdrawalStartDate=Thu May 26 04:04:51 IST 2016, declarationsAccepted=true, declarationsAcceptedDate=Thu May 26 04:04:51 IST 2016, directDebitDocumentName=null}
```

Exception that I am getting is :

```
com.force.api.ApiException: [{"message":"Cannot deserialize instance of boolean from VALUE_STRING value Yes or request may be missing a required field at [line:1, column:448]","errorCode":"JSON_PARSER_ERROR"}]
```

At the specified line & column , the property is a Boolean & I am using true as value over there, so Ideally there shouldn't be any problems.

Please help

Comment: Are you sure the JSON is valid? How are you generating it ?

Comment: The error says its expecting a json boolean, but has a string value of "Yes". How are you generating the JSON?

Answer (score 0):

Seems, your JSON is invalid, because JSON-deserializer expects Boolean value (true or false), but it get String ("Yes"), error message say it.

How do you generate this JSON?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the JSON you're getting; it must be an invalid field value.
I had gotten the same issue, due to invalid data in fields. Particularly check for the `Date` field. If you check the JSON through postman you will see the issue.